# Erro ao Salvar imagem em diretório - PHP/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, html, front-end, canvas

Olá, estou tentando terminar uma parte de um sistema, onde o usuário desenha a sua assinatura e após a ação, a  Imagem Canvas e enviada ao diretório, porém quando vou abrir a imagem Salva aparece o seguinte erro:
The image "https://br918.hostgator.com.br:2083/cpsess0222983772/view/home1%2fdsenv18%2pagina.life%2TESTE%2fpagina%2fimg/assinatura.png" Cannot be displayed bacause it contains error.

Algum de vocês poderia me ajudar?

PHP

```
$data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);

$fp = fopen("img/assinatura.png", 'wb');

fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    function salvarImagem(a){ 

    var meucanvas = document.getElementById('newSignature');

    var arquivo = document.getElementById('arquivo');

    /*Comentário: a variavel "a" será o nome do arquivo, use aspas para chamar a função */
    arquivo.download = a;
    arquivo.href = meucanvas.toDataURL();

    function signatureSave(url, name, fn, canvas, type) {

        var data = document.getElementById("assinatura.png").toDataURL();    
        $.post("assinatura.png", {
            imageData : data
        }, function(data) {
            alert('imagem salva');
        });
    }
```

Comment: meucanvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

Comment: Onde está `arquivo.href = meucanvas.toDataURL();` faça `arquivo.href =meucanvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");`

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário Augusto, eu alterei a linha de código
DE:  arquivo.href = meucanvas.toDataURL();

POR:    arquivo.href = meucanvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

Porém o erro ainda persiste :(

Comment: Que pena, eu vou pesquisar mais se encontrar algo que lhe ajude o informarei.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Augusto, vou continuar tentando resolver, obrigado pelo seu tempo.